# Symfony - get parameters.yml with front Controller

Tags: php, symfony, legacy

I have a legacy application.

I must get some parameters from parameters.yml in FrontController (app.php or app_dev.php) before system initialize Symfony Security Firewall. This parameter is path to config file ( this config is outside my project - config is required for connect to "library" with my model). 
Model is outside my project.

I must include this library by "include" function, composer drops.

In my system I have securityController, and userProvider which connect to database by "library".

So I don't know how can I get parameter with paramters.yml 
in FrontController.

Comment: Just use the Yaml component (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html) to load the file.  Not quite as nice perhaps as using the Symfony configuration system but it's easy enough.

Comment: Have your tried using `$this->container->getParameter('name')`? I don't know if it has legacy support though.

Comment: Thank's Cerad . It's work.

Comment: @JohnnyDew You can't use this in a front controller as it doesn't extend the Controller class. And even if it did, the Kernel may not be loaded yet which means the parameters.yml file hasn't been read yet. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you couldn't, Symfony Firewall is always be run before the request hit to controller.

So in your scenario, I think you should go to your security event listener (not sure what is the type of firewall you are using, x509, simple token...), so you can get parameter normally by `$container->getParameter()` and store it in somewhere, then controller can read it